# Corresponding C++ code of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, c++, activexobject

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var vc = new ActiveXObject("NetLimiter.VirtualClient");
vc.Connect("localhost"/*addr*/, ""/*port or pipe*/);
var newRuleId = vc.SetRule(
    "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe",
    "limit",// rule type
    "in", // for download (incoming)
    "Internet",// zone
    true, // rule is enabled
    "1024", // 1024 Bytes
    "");
```

It is a script to enable NetLimiter's bandwidth limiting feature. But I need to implement it in C++. I cant seem to figure out the usage of ActiveX objects in C++.
Please help.

Comment: I chanced upon this link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a1b380e-d4c7-4bd3-8090-a25e28889bb3/c-equivalent-of-javascript-activexobjectservernametypename-location?forum=vclanguage but cant seem to understand what exactly is to be done

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you want `CLSIDFromProgID`, then `CoCreateInstance` followed by invoking a couple of member functions.

Comment: How do i locate my com server component?